# Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, authentication

error in bcrypt with hashing password

```
password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8),
confirmpassword: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.confirmpassword, 8)
```

how to solve the error
tell about it

Comment: Hi, why mongodb tag?

Comment: this api connect with mongodb as database

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is the error? On mongo side or nodejs? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)